# Aggregate statistics per-day even if missing records

Tags: php, mongodb

Trying to get statistics from the past x days.
This works except for the days where I don't have data for.
Now I could work around this with a PHP script, but i'd rather have it say "0" at the count if there is no record on said day.

TLDR; i want to count back from today to 30 days ago and get the amount of records per-day even if there are no records (0).

```
    /**
     * Get Multi Count
     */
    public static function getMultiCount() {

        global $mongo;

        $timestamps = [];
        for($i = 30; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $timestamps[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$i.' days'));
        }

        $result = [];
        foreach(array_keys(self::$config) as $collection) {
            $datecol = self::$config[$collection]['datecol'];
            $ops = [
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        "_id" => [
                            '$dateToString' => [
                                "format" => "%Y-%m-%d",
                                'date' => '$' . $datecol
                            ]
                        ],
                        "count" => [
                            '$sum' => 1
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$sort' => [
                        '_id' => 1
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$match' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            '$in' => $timestamps
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            $aggregation = $mongo->aggregate($collection, $ops);
            foreach($aggregation as $k => $values) {
                $result[$collection]['labels'][] = $values['_id'];
                $result[$collection]['counts'][] = $values['count'];
                $result[$collection]['background_colors'][] = "rgba(" . rand(10, 255) . "," . rand(10, 255) . "," . rand(80, 255) . ",0.4)";
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }
```

My goal is to get something like this for 30 days...

```
  ["docdata_errors"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["labels"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2019-09-10"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2019-09-17"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2019-09-19"
    }
    ["counts"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
      [1]=>
      int(4)
      [2]=>
      int(6)
    }
    ["background_colors"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) "rgba(119,93,143,0.4)"
      [1]=>
      string(20) "rgba(32,150,160,0.4)"
      [2]=>
      string(19) "rgba(92,87,255,0.4)"
    }
  }
```

Though since I don't have data for all of the days, it'll return 30 indexes apart from the ones that aren't recorded; the ones I don't have data for.

Comment: I edited my question. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your data source to create the dates in the array, you can loop over a DateTime object. Set an end date and count down from the current date until you reach it.

Like this:

```
$endDate = new DateTime();
$endDate->modify('-29 days');

for($currentDate = new DateTime(); $currentDate > $endDate; $currentDate->modify('-1 day')) {
    // Check if there is data for the current day using $currentDate->format('Y-m-d') to 
    // compare against the date string in your data source.
    // If there is data, use it. Otherwise create an entry from the date in 
    // $currentDate and substitute 0 as the count.
}
```